# COMO MUDA FONTE JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

Estou querendo trocar a fonte de um texto na linguagem javascript.
Quero colocar a fonte Digital 7.

Parte do código de texto:

```
function text (){
        ctx.font = "40pt Italic";
        ctx.fillText("teste", 100,100);

     }
```

Código completo:

```
<!doctype html>
```

MEU JOGO
      
         canvas {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            bottom: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            right: 0px;
            margin: auto;
         }

```
  <script>
     // variáveis do jogo

     var img = new Image();
         img.src = "imagens/marFundo.png"

     var canvas, ctx, ALTURA, LARGURA, frames = 0,




     navio = {
        x: 500,
        y: 400,
        altura: 100,
        largura: 100,
        cor: "#ff4e4e",
        

        desenha: function(){
            ctx.fillStyle = this.cor;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.largura, this.altura);
        }
     };

     function main() {
        ALTURA  = window.innerHeight;
        LARGURA = window.innerWidth;

        
        LARGURA = 1800;
        ALTURA  = 900;
        

        canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = LARGURA;
        canvas.height = ALTURA;
        canvas.style.border = "1px solid #000";

        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
       
        roda();
     } // main



     function roda(){
        atualiza();
        desenha();
        text();

        window.requestAnimationFrame(roda);
     }


     function text (){
        ctx.font = "40pt Italic";
        ctx.fillText("teste", 100,100);

     }

     function atualiza(){
        frames++;
       }

     function desenha(){
        ctx.fillStyle = "#50beff";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, LARGURA, ALTURA);
        
        navio.desenha();
     }

     
     window.addEventListener("keydown", movimenta)
     function movimenta(e){
        var key = e.keyCode;
        if(key === ESQUERDA){
            navio.x -= velocidade
        }
        if(key === DIREITA){
            navio.x += velocidade
        }
        if(key === CIMA){
            navio.y -= velocidade
        }
        if(key === BAIXO){
            navio.y += velocidade
        }
     }
     

     var CIMA = 87, BAIXO = 83, ESQUERDA = 65, DIREITA = 68;
     var velocidade = 20;
     // inicializa o jogo
     


     main();



  </script>
```

Comment: No caso você precisaria mudar o fontFamily, aplicando style direto no elemento:\
Do mesmo jeito que você já aplicou os outros styles:\
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_fontfamily.asp

Answer (score 0):

Da forma que você está codificando, aplicando no Canvas, você poderá colocar o font-family na sua função text, no ctx.font, da seguinte forma:

```
function text (){
    ctx.font = "40pt Digital-7 Italic";
    ctx.fillText("teste", 100,100);
}
```

Certifique-se que este tipo de fonte esteja instalada ou ao menos apontando para um destino que a disponibilize.

Referência: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_font.asp